# The key value at position 0 of the call to 'DbSet<RepositoryFilter>.Find' was ohif type 'int', which does not match the property type of 'long'

Tags: .net, entity

The "ID" property in my entity is "long", why isn't the int parameter automatically be converted to long when call is made to Find(..) method ?